# Changing URL variables without page reload

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, reload

everyone.
I have a problem. This problem is solved perfectly in Facebook.
I have a page very similar to facebook feeds. There are some photos on this page. Clicking in the photos - we have a window that appears over all content. And we can see that on facebook URL address is changed , but all the background content doesn't reload. And we see that each photo has it's own url with get parameters.

Is there any solutions how to change URL parameters without page reloading. Without using anchors (#) and HTML5. As it implemented in facebook.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript use the location.hash to update your url:

```
<script>
    location.hash = 'yourpage';
</script>
```

Your url will be updated to = > http://www.yourdomain.com/#yourpage

You can use also push state for HTML5

```
window.history.pushState(data, "Title", "/new-url");
```

**More Info**
http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate